# Phone Screen Blackouts and respond only to Power Key Long Press

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-moto-g

I have Moto G with Bootloader unlocked and I have installed TWRP Recovery and I was using CM-12 Nightly Build.

The device was working fine but now The device just Blackouts after reboot and I am unable to access any control of device but when I press Power button for couple of seconds, it shows Reboot/power off/Airplane mode option.

I am able to hear caller ringtones and everything seems to be working fine except the screen is completely black.

Comment: Have you tried flashing a different nightly build to verify it isn't the nightly you flashed?

Comment: Yes, I have verified the Nightly Build version and after installing CM12, the phone was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched off my phone and then reboot in Fastboot Mode using **Power + Volume Down** key and then chosen recovery.

In recovery mode I choose **Wipe** and then **Format Data** then typed Yes and hit Go

This will take some time and the phone will reboot and now it's working fine.

Note : Take backup of data before formatting, you can take backup by connecting phone to your PC via USB and Copying all data on PC.